# Runtime errors with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, c++17

Consider the below code snippets

```
constexpr int divide( int x, int y)
{
    return (x/y);
}

constexpr int div_by_zero( int x)
{
    return (x/0);
}
```

**Case 1 :**

```
int x = divide(10,0);
```

This compiles successfully (with both gcc and clang) but produces the below runtime error.

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

**Case 2 :**

```
int y = div_by_zero(10);
```

This gives a Compiler error,

> (g++ -std=c++17) division by zero is not a constant expression
>
> NOTE : clang does not throw error even in this case

And also Compiler warnings:

> (clang++ -std=c++17), division by zero is undefined
>   [-Wdivision-by-zero]
>
> (g++ -std=c++17), division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]

For Case 1, why the compiler does not complain even when the value for second argument is known(i.e. zero) during the compile time ?

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/g/9hdi9b)
divide(10,2); generates below assembly code

```
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 5
```

divide(10,0); generates below assembly code

```
  mov esi, 0
  mov edi, 10
  call divide(int, int)
```

There is call to divide() when the input is zero. The same is evaluated at compile time when non-zero values are the input to the function. If a compiler is able to find out and call the method instead of evaluating, why an error can't be thrown ?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `divide(10, 0)` doesn't warn is a Quality of Implementation (QoI) issue. You could file a bug with gcc about it. But note that such arbitrary constant tracking isn't always feasible.

But the fact that `div_by_zero(10)` doesn't compile is slightly different. From [[dcl.constexpr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5):

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object ([basic.start.static]), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

One of the restrictions of what constitutes a core constant express is that it cannot invoke [undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.6), which includes [division by zero](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4.sentence-2).

So for `divide()`, there are arguments that you can pass that would make the call a valid constant expression. But for `div_by_zero()`, there does not exist *any* argument you can provide to make it a constant expression - which makes the program ill-formed.

Answer (score -1):

Your functions are `constexpr`, this means that they will be evaluated as `constexpr` (compile-time) **when the context allows it**. In your usage, the context isn't `constexpr` so it **defers the calculation to runtime**. https://godbolt.org/g/Jo5GyL

```
int x = div(10, 0); // x isn't a constexpr var, calculation in runtime
constexpr int y = div(10, 0); // y is constexpr, calculation in compile-time + error
```

On your second example, the division part is well-defined: `x / 0`. That's why the compiler knows that this will fail and reports the error **even if the function isn't invoked at compile-time** (again, lack of `constexpr` in var `y`).